# Load Balancer with JBoss 7

Tags: apache, jboss7.x, load-balancing

I tried several tutorials and am frustrated, because they are all outdated with different directory names and broken links:

(ex. https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss;jsessionid=1569CBFB7C3096C59C977CD3F7159A32 )

I have an J2EE Ear Project I deploy via JBoss 7. I want to deploy the project on two JBoss instances (on the same machine) and have a load balancer in front of it. It looks like Apache and mod_jk are the normal solution here, so I tried. I have a Debian OS and apache2 installed.

But at first, there's a problem building the mod_jk.so, because he needs apxs-configs. I only found apxs2, and it kind of worked. At the end I found a mod_jk.so file in my /usr/lib/apache2/modules folder.

Now which is the APACHE_HOME dir? I guess /etc/apache2/, but there is no modules folder there, no http.conf, no conf-folder (although a conf.d-folder). So trying to follow a tutorial becomes impossible.

Does anyone know an updated tutorial? Or another way of achieving it? Anything helps,

Thank you.